# Troubles using React with Sublime

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having a problem using React with Sublime. I'm new to React. I can't view my html file. Something's obviously missing or broken but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

I'm going to show you my three files that I'm using (.js, .html, .css). I think the problem has to do with the files not recognizing each other or something like that.

This is the first file, it's just a really basic HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.6.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.6.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testReact.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the second:-

```
html,body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.butt{
  margin-top: 36px;
}

div#testId{
  margin-top: 36px;
  padding-bottom: 36px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 500px;

}
```

And the third is a js file where I can keep my components:-

```
const colorArr = [
  "red",
  "green",
  "purple",
  "orange",
  "black",
  "brown",
  "gold",
  "lime",
  "aqua",
  "hotpink",
  "teal"
]
class HelloWorld extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state={
      color: "blue"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let i = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      if(i < colorArr.length){
        this.setState({
          color: colorArr[i]
        });
        i++
      }else{
        i = 0;
        this.setState({
          color: colorArr[i]
        });
      }  
    }, 700)
  }

  changeState () {
    if(this.state.color.localeCompare("blue") == 0){
      this.setState({
        color: "yellow"
      });
      title.style.color = "yellow";
    }else{
      this.setState({
        color: "blue"
      });
    }

  }
  inputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      color: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {

    const styleObj = {
      backgroundColor: this.state.color,
      fontSize: 21 
    }
    return(
      <div id="testId" style={styleObj}>
        <button className="butt">
          {this.state.color}
        </button>
        <input onChange={this.inputChange.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <HelloWorld name="Hanad" /> 
  </div>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

This is the folder that I store them in. I've watched a ton of tutorials on getting started but I just don't see what's wrong with it.

I was originally coding it in code pen because I couldn't figure this problem out but I need to make a switch off it. Here's a link to my program if you want to see it actually running https://codepen.io/ismail007/pen/ZxvYoE.

[image]

Comment: @halfer you're right, people will do as they please. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give create-react-app a try, it will give you a turn-key dev environment and some template HTML/CSS/JS to go off of.  It also automates a lot of the webpack/babel stuff that you might be missing here.

Comment: I really don't want to do that right now but is create-react-app similar to just react. i'm referring to its format and code

Comment: create-react-app IS react, it's just a quick way of bootstrapping up a dev environment using npm/npx and all the supporting libraries & tools react uses.  It really takes less than 15 minutes to get to where you're looking to be with it.  Worth a shot!